# symfony 1.4 doctrine Form Bind

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, bind, validation

Perhaps simple question and I am just missing something.

I have 2 tables that have 3 of the same fields(names/types).

`occurrence` and `occurrence_queue`

```
Schema

Occurrence:
  tableName: occurrence
  columns:
    id: {the usual}
    date: {type: date}
    start_time: {type: time}
    end_time: {type: time}
    eid: {a forign key}
OccurrenceQueue:
  tableName: occurrence_queue
  columns:
    id: <-Same As Above->
    occurrence_id: {the usual}
    date: <-Same As Above->
    start_time: <-Same As Above->
    end_time: <-Same As Above->
```

I then have a module That is built off `Occurrence` i.e. doctrine:generate-module *app* *name* Occurrence

In this module I load a set of Occurrences, pretty standard so here comes the trixy part. What I want to do is load the 3 common field from `Occurrence` but when I save the form I want it to save to the `OccurrenceQueue` table instead of the `Occurrence` table.

Form like this:

```
DATE: *date picker*
Start Time: HH:MM
End Time: HH:MM
```

Here is my failed attempt at this:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST) || $request->isMethod(sfRequest::PUT));

  $this->forward404Unless($occurrence = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Occurrence')->find(array($request->getParameter('id'))), sprintf('Object occurrence does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));

  $request->setParameter('occurrence_id',$occurrence->getId());

  $occurrenceQForm = new OccurrenceQueueForm($occurrenceQueue());

  $occurrenceQForm->bind($request->getParameter($occurrenceQForm->getName(),$request->getFiles($occurrenceQForm->getName()));

  if($occurrenceQForm->isValid())
  {
    $occurrenceQForm->save();
    $this->redirect("happyness");
  }
}
```

This never validates. I **assumed** because the field and the validations were the same it would be all golden and what not, well not the case. So the question is, how do I accomplish this task?  In the end The idea is the `OccurrenceQueue` table will be used to update the `Occurrence` table.

Mahalo for the help!

Comment: Additionally I have tried this code:
`$SRQ = new OccurrenceQueue();
$SRQ->setOccurrencesId($phpc_occurrences->getOccid());
$SRQ->setStarttime($request->getPostParameter('starttime'));
$SRQ->setEndtime($request->getPostParameter('starttime'));
$SRQ->setStartdate($request->getPostParameter('startdate'));
$OQForm = new OccurrenceQueueForm($SRQ);
$OQForm->save();`

Comment: `$occurrenceQForm->bind($request->getParameter($occurrenceQForm->getName(),$request->getFiles($occurrenceQForm->getName()));` should be `$occurrenceQForm->bind($request->getParameter($occurrenceQForm->getName()),$request->getFiles($occurrenceQForm->getName());`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by "never validates" (is there an error message?) Could you also put the what `var_dump($request->getParameter($occurrenceQForm->getName()))` displays?

Comment: @greg0ire yes there are syntax errors this is psudo code not actual and I mean isValid() returns False, and this is why... var_dump returns: Null...now at least I know why it's failing but I have no idea why my request is null....?

Comment: @greg0ire however the var_dump from $request->getParameter($occurrenceForm->getName()) is :
`array(3) {
  ["startdate"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["day"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2011"
  }
  ["starttime"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["hour"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["minute"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["endtime"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["hour"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["minute"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form is never binding the **ocurrence_id**. When using a sfForm it uses the **nameFormat** (the $form->getName() part) to generate the name of that field, so for you to work try it like this:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  ...
  $occurrenceQForm = new OccurrenceQueueForm($occurrenceQueue());

  $values = $request->getParameter($occurrenceQForm->getName());
  $values['occurrence_id'] = $ocurrence->getId();
  $occurrenceQForm->bind($values,$request->getFiles($occurrenceQForm->getName()));
  ...
}
```

This is not the best way to do it but it will work. What would i really do is by passing the Ocurrence by parameter to the OcurrenceQForm like this:

```
public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  ...
  $occurrenceQForm = new OccurrenceQueueForm($occurrenceQueue(), array('ocurrence' => $ocurrence));
  ...
}
```

And in your OccurrenceForm:

```
public function OccurrenceQueueForm extends ...{
    public function configure()
    {
        ...
        if($this->getOption('ocurrence') != null){
            $this->setDefault('occurrence_id', $ocurrence->getId());
        }
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I am focusing on the wrong issue, How can I create a new form, add values to the form and then save it? That's all I am trying to do....

Comment: Well I am sorry for the mis-leading structure and set up, I clearly misunderstood quite a bit :-)
The solution is simple: Stop trying to save the FORM just save the Model....
`$occurrenceQueue->setXXX($form->getValue('desiredVal'));
$$occurrenceQueue->save();`

this works perfectly and does what I desire

Comment: The are differences between a sfForm and a doctrine form. My recommendation, if you are using a model form, use the doctrine form and always try to keep the form login inside the form, avoid form logic in the controller. Doing what you said works but you are missing the advantages of doctine forms.